# ERROR in multi main Cannot GET /dist/bundle.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

i am new to react.js. i am getting this error on production but same code is working on development. can anybody help me.when i am running this code on development.everytime webpack built and generate a dist folder this folder have a bundle.js but webpack is not build on production

```
 /home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/server-out-0.log last 10 lines:
   0|server   | Version: webpack 1.13.2
   0|server   | Time: 566ms
   0|server   |     Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
   0|server   | bundle.js  1.52 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   0|server   | chunk    {0} bundle.js (main) 28 bytes [rendered]
   0|server   |     [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
   0|server   | 
   0|server   | ERROR in multi main
   0|server   | Module not found:
   Error:Cannot resolve 'file' or   'directory'
  ./client/index.html in /var/www/html/AR/server
   0|server   |  @ multi main


  [STREAMING] Now streaming realtime logs for [all] processes
  0|server   | Error: Cannot GET /dist/bundle.js
  0|server   |     at raiseUrlNotFoundError       

 (/var/www/html/AR/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-   

found.js:20:17)
0|server   |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request]   

(/var/www/html/AR/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
 0|server   |     at trim_prefix    

 (/var/www/html/AR/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
 0|server   |     at   
 /var/www/html/AR/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
 0|server   |     at Function.process_params    

 (/var/www/html/AR/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
 0|server   |     at next    

 (/var/www/html/AR/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
 0|server   |     at SendStream.error   

(/var/www/html/AR/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-   

static/index.js:121:7)
0|server   |     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
0|server   |     at SendStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
0|server   |     at SendStream.error  

  (/var/www/html/AR/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:275:17)
```

Thanks,